# How can I programatically deselect an item in a lightning:datatable?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-datatable

I use a lightning:datatable like

```
<lightning:datatable data="{!v.filteredManageableUsers}"
    columns="{!v.userColumns}"
    keyField="Id"
    hideCheckboxColumn="{!false}"
    onrowselection="{!c.onRowSelection}"/>
```

So it shows nice checkboxes alongside every row. And I can call `getSelectedRows()` to get an array of data in each selected row.

Now how can I **deselect** a selected row through code?

Answer (score 1):

from lightning:datatable spec: the **selectedRows attribute** is a **list of keyField** values.

1. In the markup of your datatable associate the selectedRows to an attribute of type List.
2. on any desired event, retrieve the value of this attribute and removes or add the desired rows from your attribute. It will automatically update your datatable. (no need for component.find or other nasty things)

Depending on your use case, you will want to generate/maintain a map somewhere when changing your data attribute, to associate the keyfield to the value that matter for your on the row.

Don't hesitate asking for more precise answer if you have issues with the framework. And read more carefully the specs on [the component library](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/)!

Comment: Great, that should work! I'll try it out first and then accept the answer.